# Dynamic Columns that look nice

Tags: php, jquery

The ordering of this site:
https://www.capitecbank.co.za/global-one/save

Has a dynamic fixture as though the columns generate itself.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this? I assume it's jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), jQuery plugin. However, the site you mentioned uses [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)